# ViewPager Indicator like instagram

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpageindicator

Как можно создать ViewPager indicator как в инстаграмме при просмотре вложенных фотографий, то есть если элементов больше 5 , то последний круг маленький , когда мы до него доходим , он увеличивается , а два крайних становяться опять маленькими. Обьяснить сложно , легче посмотреть на вложенных фотографиях в инстаграмме

Comment: Что за вложенные фотографии в инстаграме? Не совсем понял по объяснению

Comment: @PeterSamokhin пользователь может прикрепить к одному посту до 10 фотографий в инстграмме, я об этих вложенных фотографиях

Comment: В вопрос можно вставлять картинки. Скриншот того, что вы хотите был бы очень кстати здесь.